# Track custom event using Salesforce marketing cloud iOS SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush

Is there any way to track custom events using [SalesForce Marketing Cloud iOS SDK](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/JB4A-SDK-iOS)? I can see an analytics class in the SDK called `ETAnalytics`, but it has very limited tracking options -- pageView, cartContents, cartConversion --. However, I need to track some custom data, kind of small json payloads. In the [documentation](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-iOS/features/analytics.html), I found references to [Personalization Builder](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/personalization_builder). In Personalization Builder, there is a [topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_track_event.htm&type=5) describing tracking of custom data, but its all java script and I am not sure how can we achieve it using iOS SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of 20180124, you cannot track a custom event with the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDKs.  I suggest you open a Voice of Customer (VOC) request via your account manager as the only way to get things like this added is to make sure your request is heard.